# how to add locale to router-link in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-i18n

I have huge vue application with a lot of `<router-link>` and `:to`.

I just implement i18n in my application. now I need to add the `$i18n.locale` prefix to each router-link.

for example:

```
 <router-link :to="`${i18n.locale}/login`">…</router-link>
```

Is there easy way to add the locale prefix without change all the `router-link` or `:to` in my code?

Comment: Did you try that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321530/prefix-routes-with-locale-in-vue-js-using-vue-i18n? It seems to be related to your question.

Comment: yes, but is a different question because I have set the router to be :lang like in the stackoverfow question. my question is about the router-link link. when I have link and now I need to add prefix for every router-link

Comment: I thought (didn't check, just a suggestion) that `router-link` with `to: "/login"` which is placed inside child route (parent route will have `path: "/:lang"`) will do that automatically: `/en` will be taken from parent `route` and `/login` will be taken from `router-link` in nested view...